# Python metaprogramming, adding functions at runtime

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Are there any problems with this code? It works, but is it the 'pythonic way' to introspect and create new functions on the fly? For example, are there advantages to using class attributes over the example **init** method below? Is there an overall better way to do metaprogramming like this? And is there a better way to whitelist inputs? I know the whitelisting isn't very useful in this context but included it for inquiry.

```py
import sys
import re

class Convert:

    whitelist = {
        'pounds': 'kilos',
        'kilos': 'pounds',
        'meters': 'feet',
        'feet': 'meters',
        'farenheit': 'celsius',
        'celsius': 'farenheit',
        'volts': 'gigavolts'
    }

    kilos_to_pounds = lambda self, p: 2.20462  * p
    pounds_to_kilos = lambda self, k: 0.453592 * k
    pounds_to_grams = lambda self, p: p / 1000
    kilos_to_grams = lambda self, k: k * 1000
    meters_to_feet = lambda self, m: 3.28084 * m
    feet_to_meters = lambda self, f: 0.3048 * f
    farenheit_to_celsius = lambda self, f: (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)
    celsius_to_farenheit = lambda self, c: (c * 9.0/5.0) + 32.0

    # can do this also, but is it better? why?:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_to_z = lambda x: x - x

    def is_allowed(self, source, dest):
        allowed = {
            source: self.whitelist.get(source, None)
            for k,v in self.whitelist.items()
            if source in self.whitelist and self.whitelist[source] == v
        }

        if not allowed:
            raise Exception(f'Cannot convert {source} to {dest}.')
        return True

    def add(self, func, source, dest):
        if self.is_allowed(source, dest):
            setattr(self, '{}_to_{}'.format(source, dest), func)
            return True
        return False

    def convert(self, source, dest, value):
        if self.is_allowed(source, dest):
            val = getattr(self, '{}_to_{}'.format(source, dest))(value)
            return val
        return None


# note: none of these numbers are `100% accurate or precise`
converter = Convert()
print(converter.convert('pounds', 'kilos', 10.0) == 4.53592)
print(converter.convert('kilos', 'pounds', 10.0) == 22.0462)
print(converter.convert('kilos', 'grams', 10.0) == 10_000)
print(converter.convert('pounds', 'grams', 10.0) == 4535.92)
print(converter.convert('meters', 'feet', 10.0) == 32.8084)
print(converter.convert('feet', 'meters', 10.0) == 3.048)
print(round(converter.convert('farenheit', 'celsius', 10.0), 2) == -12.22)
print(converter.convert('celsius', 'farenheit', 10.0) == 50.0)

volts_to_gigavolts = lambda v: v * 0.000000001
converter.add(volts_to_gigavolts, 'volts', 'gigavolts')
print(converter.convert('volts', 'gigavolts', 100))


maxwells_to_ohms = lambda Convert, e: (e**-e**2) * e**2
converter.add(maxwells_to_ohms, 'maxwells', 'ohms')
print(converter.convert('maxwells', 'ohms', 120))
```

Comment: Your design doesn't allow converting feet to both meters and inches, since dictionary keys have to be unique. You should probably have a list of targets, or use an array of tuples.

Comment: You might want to take a look at existing conversion packages, for instance [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io), either to use them or to peek at the source code.